# Free() a partially freed array of strings C

Tags: c, arrays, string, free

Assume that I have an array of strings, some of which are already free'd, as an example:

```
char **array;
array = malloc(20*sizeof(char*));

for(i=0;i<arr_size;i++)
{
    array[i]='\0';
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

Is this a correct way to do it? Because I still seem to get some memory leaks,
in my case an array of 20 strings where 9 are already freed.

I guess the question is how to go about freeing "freed" strings.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this compile? What is the declaration of array?

Comment: char ** array; array =malloc(20*sizeof(char*));

Comment: So why the single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the question is how to go about freeing "freed" strings.

Well, you don't. You must `free` every `malloc`'ed string exactly once. Calling `free` several times on the same string will lead to undefined behaviour.

That aside, your problem is the following:

```
array[i]='\0';
```

Here, you are overwriting the value of the pointer before you `free` it.

Comment: Also, array[i] has not been malloced.  Only array has been malloced.  Freeing it will probably cause a crash.

Comment: ... And it is being assigned a character not a string

Answer (score 1):

By convention, you should always set a pointer to `NULL` after `free`-ing. Then you should check to see if the pointer is `NULL`, if not, then you can `free`. That way you can keep track of which ones have been `free`-ed and which ones haven't.

Comment: You don't even have to check for `NULL` when freeing, `free(NULL)` is harmless.

Comment: Really? That's new to me.

Comment: See for example [this standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), in 7.22.3.3/2: "If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs."

Answer (score 0):

`1 malloc()` allocation requires just `1 free()` to deallocate memory. So  `free(array);` is sufficient to deallocate the memory.

`free()` deallocating memory is counter to allocated memory dynamically using `malloc()`.

Comment: Nope. `free(array)` does not 'deallocate memory', it only frees the array of pointers, but it doesn't free the strings which are pointed to by the array's items.

Answer (score 0):

Using free(array[i]); will cause problems / strange errors as you are trying to free a pointer whose value (pointer) you have changed on the previous line.

The code
    array[i]='\0';

may not have the desired results as it is setting the pointer value not the character contents.  Perhaps sprintf(array[i],"\0"); would be better

```
char **array=NULL;  //(Helps you to give it an initial value pointing to NULL)

array = malloc(arr_size+1);  

if (!array[i])
{
// array == NULL which is not right after malloc
// there has been an error with malloc, trap and exit somehow
}
else
{
// Use array as you wish as it has been allocated, take care not to 
// run past the end of the array length
}

if (array[i]) free(array[i]);   // checks that it is not NULL anymore, as NULL does not need freeing.
```

You could expand the IF statement to:  (means that same as above, but includes forcing a freed variable to NULL)

```
if (array[i]!=NULL) 
{
 free(array[i]);   
 array[i] = NULL;
}
```